# Word for something that is interpreted differently depending on the observer?

Tags: single-word-requests

In particular, an event or situation that will be interpreted differently by people with different biases/experiences/etc.?

"Clinton's election loss was a [???] for the Democrats; to some, it meant that the party needed to move left, while others thought it meant the far left should compromise."

(No actual political commentary intended.)

Comment: ***relative***.

Comment: Just about anything can / will be. 'Open to interpretation' is in the right ballpark.

Comment: *contextual*, where the difference in the context is the observing/interpreting party.

Comment: In your sentence, perhaps "conundrum" would fit.  See MW for synonyms and related words.

Comment: A **talking-point**?

Comment: That depends on your point of view… That's a matter of opinion…

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two words that might be useful, depending on whether you want to emphasize that something is open to interpretation generally or something that is contentious.

"**Moot**", as in a moot point or moot question. Moot has taken on a negative connotation, but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moot) defines moot as in two different senses:

> **`Moot:`**
>
> 1a: open to question : DEBATABLE
>
> 1b: subjected to discussion : DISPUTED
>
> 2: deprived of practical significance : made abstract or purely academic

I think senses 1a and 1b are describing exactly the "open-endedness" of these types of questions, particularly that they prompt debate and discussion. Sense 2 is the negative connotation of the word, and is often used to be dismissive of a concern. However, senses 1a/1b are equally valid and capture what you're suggesting, but may cause some confusion with your audience as they will have to discern if you're being dismissive/critical.

"**Subjective**" is another possibility. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subjective) has a somewhat  negative definition:

> **`Subjective:`**
>
> influenced by or based on personal beliefs or feelings, rather than based on facts

On the other hand, I frequently hear people use the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subjective) definition, to capture what you're suggesting in a much more neutral, nonjudgmental way:

> **`Subjective:`**
>
> 4a(2): modified or affected by personal views, experience, or background

Answer (score -1):

Might I also suggest the word **perspective*

Ex. Each approached the debate with a different perspective.